# Webpack bundled library is different from the one in a Node.js source file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a file:

```
// in.js

var util = require('util')
console.log(typeof util.inspect.defaultOptions)
```

which when run with Node.js is worked fine:

```
C:\Users\artur\tmp>node in.js
object
```

but if i bundle it with Webpack, it stops working:

```
C:\Users\artur\tmp>webpack in.js out.js
Hash: c12d8f247c3fe30a8896
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 169ms
 Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
out.js  24.3 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./in.js 85 bytes {0} [built]
    + 4 hidden modules

C:\Users\artur\tmp>node out.js
undefined
```

I've got:

- Node.js version 7.0.0
- Webpack version 1.13.3
- npm version 3.10.8
- Windows 10

Comment: Have you got   `target: 'node',` in your webpack config?

Comment: Looks like the `util` module bundled via `webpack` is not identical to the one in Node itself. Are you expected to use this with just Node?

Comment: @Keith: No, the target is default ("web"). Tried setting it explicitly to "web" with same results

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: No, i want to bundle for web

Comment: If your bundling for web, then there is a good chance there different as util will be a polyfill.  If you beleive util inspect.defaultOption would be handy for browser you might be best contacting the developer of the polyfill. https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-util maybe post an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Library [`util`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util) is specific for node environment. You **can not** bundle it in webpack to be served in the browser.

If you want to exclude this kind of code to be bundled with webpack, you can take a look at configuration of [`externals`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) in `webpack.config` with [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals) plugin.

```
externals: require('webpack-node-externals')()
```